# 'bash_profile' missing code

Tags: bash

Using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, I edited `.bash_profile` code while following some online directions. I ended up deleting the original code and now it is lost. Can someone please tell me what the original code is?

Comment: There is no `.bash_profile` on my system at all.

Comment: `~/.profile` is present by default, and should be sufficient in most cases.

Comment: `~/.bash_profile` (and `~/.bash_login`) does not exist on Ubuntu by default. So perhaps you have deleted `~/.profile` or have you created `~/.bash_profile` previously yourself?

Answer (score 3):

A normal `.profile` looks like this:

```bsh
# ~/.profile: executed by the command interpreter for login shells.
# This file is not read by bash(1), if ~/.bash_profile or ~/.bash_login
# exists.
# see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files for examples.
# the files are located in the bash-doc package.

# the default umask is set in /etc/profile; for setting the umask
# for ssh logins, install and configure the libpam-umask package.
#umask 022

# if running bash
if [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ]; then
    # include .bashrc if it exists
    if [ -f "$HOME/.bashrc" ]; then
    . "$HOME/.bashrc"
    fi
fi

# set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists
if [ -d "$HOME/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
fi
```

Comment: This does not answer the question as the OP is specifically saying `~/.bash_profile`

Comment: I used command "emacs ~/.bash_profile" after installing emacs, this must have created a profile that was not default, and it included some code. I deleted that code and now need it back. I assume that it is the same as a normal .profile code, and therefore Videonauth has answered my question!  Thanks.